# Oauth authentication for Terraform user instead of specifiying secret / access keys

Tags: oauth, terraform

Is there a way I can specificy a OAUTH authentication for terraform to redirect for authenticating before creating resources on a particular cloud .
For eg : Instead of specifying Secret/Access keys in variables for TF_VAR value . I want terraform to redirect to a OAUTH client for authentication after and refer those credentials to carry out a API call to the AWS to create the resources mentioned in the TF file

Comment: Do you have a specific provider in mind? They all authenticate differently.

Comment: To start with  gmail account . This i what i am looking for . When i type terraform apply , it should redirect me to a browser to enter my google account ( gmail id and the password ) and use to login to AWS to create the resources mentioned in the tf file .  I do not want to specify the secret/access keys in variables.tf or TF_VAR or aws configure